# How to re-conect a remote conection trough SSH in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-access

I am having an issue with my remote SSH connection in VSCode. When I try to connect, it appears to be working normally, but after a short time it becomes disconnected and I need to reconnect. I have tried to look for a solution on how to reconnect the remote connection in VSCode, but so far I have not been successful. I would like to be able to reconnect to the remote connection in order to continue working on my processes without having to restart them. I have checked my ssh_config file, but I am not sure if there is a setting I need to change in order to reconnect to the remote connection. I would like to post this issue on StackOverflow to see if there is a solution that can help me reconnect to the remote connection in VSCode. I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60714159/is-there-a-way-to-reconnect-to-a-disconnected-vs-code-remote-ssh-connection) post but the "Reaload" functión will throw all my variables and procecess. Can someone help me please? Or at least tell me "there is not a solutión, just reload an change your ssh config file like the previous post".

Comment: Can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66334078/18359438) in the issue you mentioned solve your problem? `Developer: Reload Window`

Comment: That's the post I've checked and wrote in the question. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem. I think it doesn't have a solution and if it has, it depends on a lot of characteristics of the server. Thanks btw